# React Native stuck on white screen IOS

Tags: react-native, expo

My app is working fine on the web but stuck on the XCode Simulator upon running the initiating cmd `expo start`

[image]

List of files

[image]

Tried removing `node_modules` , `package-lock` etc but nothing seems to work

App has been reloaded numerous times but only works on web.

Comment: Can you show me the file lists?

Comment: where can I found that @TalhaAkbar

Comment: on your left side of nav bar. I need to see your whole project files.

Comment: Do you get any logs in console or debugger? If you do get logs then please share those

Comment: Share a minimal example where this happens as well, or there is nothing that we can do.

Comment: just edited the question @TalhaAkbar Get a log of the files in the debugger as I normally do when everything is working ok so unsure.

Answer (score 2):

I found where the problem was, having `expo-splash-screen` was causing this issue. I was using this in a `useEffect` to load my project font but having removed this package resolved the issue.